# I'm trying to figure out if this could somehow be overflowed

Tags: c, overflow, buffer-overflow, integer-overflow

hope your having a nice day;
so i have the following code that i want to know if it would somehow overflow at some point ::

```
static void * myalloc(size_t len) {
    void * p = malloc(len);
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "end of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return p;
}

static void * copy_buf(void * buf, uint32_t count, uint32_t be) {
    uint32_t * p = NULL;
    if (buf != NULL) {
        p = myalloc(count * 4);
        memcpy(p, buf, count * 4);
     }  
// more code
  return p;
}
```

if it did not overflow, would something else cause it to do so, i mean if the variables changed. or the parameters changed (not the data type of course, but the value of them)
this question looks like [memcpy overflow boundary exploit? (smashing the stack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236124/memcpy-overflow-boundary-exploit-smashing-the-stack) so i hope it gets the same reaction :)

thank you for your help, the full source code is much bigger (more than a one file and more that 2000 lines of code for each one), but this is one of the parts that i am concerned about...

have a nice day.

Comment: Depending on what you pass to `copy_buf` as `void * buf` and `uint32_t count`, the `memcpy` may try to read beyond the end of the memory pointed to by `buf`.

Comment: @Bodo what values can cause such a case ... I'm not a  good c programmer, and not into secure programming yet, this is my first project for college, and sadly they don't want bugs in it !

Answer (score 1):

`copy_buf(buf, count, be)` assumes the `count` is the number of `uint32_t` pointed to by `buf`.  In which case the below is better.

```
// static void * copy_buf(void * buf, uint32_t count, uint32_t be)
static void * copy_buf(uint32_t * buf, uint32_t count, uint32_t be)
```

If OP is using `count` as the size of the object pointed to by `buf`, then code's scaling by 4 is wrong and may explain the "overflow".

See also [@Bodo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66530945/im-trying-to-figure-out-if-this-could-somehow-be-overflowed/66531234#comment117613649_66530945) about reading too much.

---

"Overflow" possible in at least 2 cases. As all deal with extreme values, I do not think looking at this small portion of OP's code is the case of OP's woes, but here are some ways "overflow" occurs:

**`size_t` narrower than `uint32_t`**

Conversion of product `count * 4` (an `uint32_t`) to `size_t` may not fit in the `size_t` range and result in the wrong size allocation.

**`size_t` same or greater range as `uint32_t`**

Product `count * 4` outside `uint32_t` range and overflows before assignment to a `size_t`.

---

Show improved code:

Use a common size type.

OP's `copy_buf(buf, 0, 123)` is not an overflow problem, but could cause code to exit, even with ample memory.  Test for 0.

```
static void *myalloc(size_t len) {
  void * p = malloc(len);
  if (p == NULL && len > 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "end of memory\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return p;
}

static void *copy_buf(const void * buf, size_t count) {
  uint32_t * p = NULL;
  if (buf != NULL) {
    if (count > SIZEMAX/sizeof *p) {
      fprintf(stderr, "count too big\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    p = myalloc(sizeof *p * count);
    memcpy(p, buf, sizeof *p * count);
  }  
  // more code
  return p;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this detailed explanation ... but as I said im not that good at secure programming and such things, and my code didn't cause an overflow while running, I went curious since I know that memory manipulation (copying...) is responsible for some big bugs ... and I didn't actually understand all what you posted (althogh I really appreciate it) but can a attacker exploit my code ?  And how !?

Comment: @muhammadAli Exploits: 1) Use `count == 0` to force an `exit()`.  2) Use a `count > SIZEMAX/4` to under allocate without an overflow detection.  3) Using `buf == NULL` may casue issues in `// more code`.

Comment: with all my respect man, I don't git it, I need to know if my code is vulnerable to a buffer overflow or not

Comment: @muhammadAli Yes it is vulnerable to buffer overflow.  Sorry if my explanations are not clear enough.

Comment: no man, I'm just too stupid to get it, I appreciate your help... if this code is vulnerable then I got another one vulnerable for sure ... but since I can't post for like 3 days after this post I'll wait 

Comment: @muhammadAli  Tip: Best to post a [MCVE] with sample inputs

Answer (score 0):

It will not overflow while the several `4`s you have spread in the code are true `4`s.  Let me explain myself:

The problem is that you have assumed that some data type is four bytes wide, which is too far to assume.  A better choice should be to put it as `sizeof (SOME_TYPE)`, or even better, as `sizeof SOME_VARIABLE`.  In this last case, if you change the type or the number of elements of an array, there's no problem, because the `sizeof` operator handles it.  But as you have writen just `4`, the code is not only ununderstandable but unreadable.  Specify what is this `4` you use so much and then you'll have clean, readable, and non-overflow dangerous code.

**Possible workarounds:** change `4` by `sizeof (uint32_t)`, or better, change it by `sizeof *p`, which is the size of the object you want to multiply by the value of `count`.